# Amazon SES Client getSendStatistics args

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

What are the arguments of getSendStatistics in detail??

The original docs choose to sum them up into an "array args"...
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetSendStatistics.html

BTW I am using that in Symfony, if that is somehow relevant:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Answer (score 1):

Apparently that IS the argument. An empty array. I don't know why though.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1128